# Quartz - Spring - Java - Jobstore. how to set job in completed state

Tags: java, state, jobs, quartz, crontrigger

I ask for help, I have jobs scheduled through quartz in a job shop, everything works some jobs that call procedures on Oracle. I would like to put the job in a complete state when a procedure returns a certain result. I can pause the job but not in completed.

```
if(!result.substring(0,4).equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                    fase_1.callJobResult("JOB_RESULT", key.getName().toString(), key.getGroup().toString(), strJobex+":"+parameter, result);
                }else {
                    // I pause the job because it has been completed
                    try {
                        fase_1.callJobResult("JOB_RESULT", key.getName().toString(), key.getGroup().toString(), strJobex+":"+parameter,"SUCCESS. Il job : " + key.getName().toString().toUpperCase() + " job completed");
                        System.out.println(result);

                        //Scheduler scheduler;
                        SchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
                        Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();

                        JobKey jobKey = new JobKey(key.getName().toString(), key.getGroup().toString());
                        //scheduler.pauseJob(jobKey); // example this work

                        Trigger trigger = jobExecutionContext.getTrigger();
                        //Trigger.CompletedExecutionInstruction.NOOP.SET_TRIGGER_COMPLETE()


                        TriggerListner tl = new TriggerListner();
                        tl.triggerComplete(trigger, jobExecutionContext, CompletedExecutionInstruction.SET_TRIGGER_COMPLETE);
```

Comment: "Complete" indicates that the trigger has not remaining fire-times in its schedule, so, why dont't you simply unschedule the trigger (e.g. with scheduler.unscheduleJob(triggerKey("trigger1", "group1"));)?

Comment: Because unschedule deletes the job from the jobstore, and therefore I lose the history of the executed jobs.

Comment: Could you add your Quartz configuration?  I ask so because I think you should try with https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.3.0/org/quartz/spi/JobStore.html#triggeredJobComplete-org.quartz.spi.OperableTrigger-org.quartz.JobDetail-org.quartz.Trigger.CompletedExecutionInstruction- .
Example 17 here https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.quartz.impl.triggers.CronTriggerImpl . Which JobStore are you using?

Comment: Hi, @Stefano my dependency in pom is `  <dependency>
         <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
         <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.3</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
         <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.3</version>
     </dependency>`    Do you think I should update to version 2.3.0 ?

Comment: Please add the whole pom and Quartz configuration to your question.